# Batch Faulting Child Relationship in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a pretty simple little schema that looks like this:

Trail --> Segment --> Coordinate

All of the proper relationships are in place to make this work, and they certainly let me do something like this:

```
NSArray *trails = <query all trails>

for (Trail *trail in trails) {
    for (Segment *segment in trail.segments) {
        for (Coordinate *coordinate in segment.coordinates) {
            //do something with coords
        }
    }
}
```

Coming from a Django background, I was delighted with this, and assumed the fewest possible queries would be run against sqlite3.  Wrong!  There is a query made for each and every object in these loops.

I've now read the Core Data documentation on faulting, I understand what's going on, although I would really like to know what the best practices are for dealing with a situation like this.  I need every single object in memory (the coords model has ~100,000 objects) because they are all used at one moment to plot a trail on a map.

How should I deal with this ultra lazy loading?

Comment: Relevant: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW6

I believe that prefetching child objects in a one-to-many relationship is possible, and so is batch faulting such a relationship after loading the parent object. I might test both methods and post a more complete answer than Martin R's later if I get the chance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:` method of `NSFetchRequest` for this. From the documentation:

> Prefetching allows Core Data to obtain related objects in a single
>   fetch (per entity), rather than incurring subsequent access to the
>   store for each individual record as their faults are tripped.

So in your initial fetch request for the trails you could add

```
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"segments", @"segments.coordinates", nil]]
```

(I never tried this with 2 levels deep, only with one level.)

Comment: I looked into that method, but I think it's only for prefetching relationships that are 1:1 (like child prefetching it's parent, or in this case, segment prefetching it's trail).  I did try it anyway, and no luck.  Thanks though!

Comment: There is an error in my answer: It must be  ... arrayWithObjects:@"segments", @"segments.coordinates", nil! I just tried it and it seems to work. If you set "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3" as launch argument, you can see that all data are retrieved in the initial fetch request. This is done with 3 sqlite queries, independent of the number of objects. The first sqlite query is for all Trail objects. The second is for all Segment objects which belong to one of the trails, and the third query is for all Coordinate objects which belong to one of the segments.

Comment: I noticed that error when you originally posted it and (thought) I corrected it when I saw my previous results, but now that I try it again, it looks like it's working.  Thanks!